# Database driver error when loading data with Informatica into Oracle XE 10 g

Tags: oracle, driver, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I'm trying to load within an Oracle XE 10g database. When I run an Informatica PowerCenter Workflow, I get a following error:

```
CMN_1022    Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [Database driver event...
    Error occurred loading library [pmora8.dll]. 
    System error encountered is 193. 
    Error text is 
        %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    .]
```

Any ideas what might be causing this error? My environment is as follows:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Informatica PowerCenter 9.5
- Oracle XE 10 G

Powercenter repository is on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Are your PATH and LIBRARY_PATH environment variables set up correctly? Is the library pmora8.dll where it should be?

Comment: I have e.g Oracle in my PATH variable: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;. But I cannot find LIBRARY_PATH variable, what should be its value? Where pmora8.dll should reside?

Comment: Set it to `%ORACLE_HOME%/lib`. Not sure about `pmora8.dll`, but I suppose somewhere in the Informatica directory (I've never used Informatica)

Comment: I did that but it did not help. I have several pmora8.dll in my Informatica folders, I think it is fine.

Comment: " %1 is not a valid Win32 application" maybe it's somehow pointing at the 64 bit DLL incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few variables that need to be set before your informatica runtime environment can be considered ready to run jobs...

1. PM_HOME - must point to the directory where informatica is installed
2. LIBRARY_HOME or LD_LIBRARY_PATH - depending upon whether you are in windows world or unix (respectively), this variable should include library files from informatica. Typically this should include $PM_HOME/bin
3. PATH - this must include the executables from informtica as well as any other subsystems you might be accessing.

Its possible that these variables are not setup/created in windows/unix when you first install the informatica software, don't hesitate in creating them afresh.  However, if they already exist (e.g. PATH would exist already), make sure you append (and not replace) the new values.

hth

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that you have installed 32-bit Oracle client and 64-bit PowerCenter.

A 64 bit PowerCenter works only with 64 bit oracle client. Please install 64-bit Oracle client, restart PowerCenter services and check if the session succeeds.

Few comments about the discussion in this thread:

- Make sure %oracle_home%/bin is added as a first entry in the PATH variable. Informatica recommends so.
- After you change PATH variable, Informatica services needs to be restarted for that to take effect.
- pmora8.dll will be available in %INFA_HOME%/server/bin
- PM_HOME is for PowerCenter 7.x or earlier versions. From 8.x it is INFA_HOME