# Setting up informatica repository service

Tags: oracle, repository, etl, informatica

I'm new to Informatica. I ran into problems creating a repository service. (I have searched here and the internet, and nothing seems to work.)

So here is my whole setup

- Vsphere server 1: installed  Windows Server 2008 (64 bit), 11g (64 bit)
- Vsphere server 2: installed Windows Server 2003 (32 bit), Informatica server 8.6.0 (32 bit)

My laptop: installed Windows 7 (64 bit)

I created a user in 11g for Informatica

- inno_informatica
- grant connect
- dba
- resource

created another user in 11g for repository

- inno_repo
- grant connect
- dba
- resource

After I successfully installed Informatica on server 2, I tried to setup repository service, but I got an error saying that it can't connect to database.

So now the repository service is there on the left-hand panel, but there is a message in red indicating

> The service did not start due to the following error: unable to connect to the repository inno_repo on database Orcl.132.1.123. Check the Log for more Information

When I check the log,  two messages got my attention:

1. database driver event.... Error occurred loading library [pmora8.dll]. System error encountered is 126. Error text is The specified module could not be found..
2. unable to connect to the repository inno_repo orcle.132.1.123

Also, I just want to point out the database for repository service and Informatica domain is the same one, but with different schemas. And no Informatica client, or Oracle client is installed on Server 2.

*So*

1. Do I have to install Oracle Client on Server 2?
2. Are certain environmental variables needed in order to problem this problem?
3. What about ports? What ports are needed for Informatica?
4. If none of the above could solve the problem, then what should be done?

Comment: Does this help at all (with the connection)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637513/database-driver-error-when-loading-data-with-informatica-into-oracle-xe-10-g

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install Oracle on your second server as well. Install and then update the tnsnames.ora with the connect string entry. After these steps you can try to configure the repository service in Admin console with the connection string.